# Save facial expressions on rigged characters

Tags: pose-mode

I have a rigged character. I want to have a library of many facial expressions for it. However I don't know how to (if it is even possible) save only the facial pose data instead of data for the whole body. My wish is that I would then be able to apply a specific expression to the character without changing its head position and rotation. Is it possible and if yes, then how?

Comment: Yes this is very possible, Check out the docs for PoseLib. You can save the poses of selected bones on an armature and use them for other poses. Sorry I don't have anything with armature loaded, so I can't check to give you more detail.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to store parts of an armature. Did you try to store the pose with only the bones you want selected?